# Help, some proof about convergent sequence.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(x_n)$ be sequence, s.t, for every $n$, there is a $m$, $m>n$, and $x_m>x_n$,

prove that if $(x_n)$ converges to $L$,then $x_n< L$, for all $n$.

The hint is prove by contradiction, but I really don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $x_N\geq L$ for some integer $N$.
Then by hypothesis we can find and integer $n_1$ auch that $n_1>N$ and $x_{n_1}>x_N$.

Again we can find an integer $n_2$ such that $n_2>n_1$ and $x_{n_2}>x_{n_1}$.

Continuing this way, we can can construct an increasing subsequence $(x_{n_r})_{r\in\mathbb N}$ of $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$.

Since any subsequence of a convergent subsequence also converges to the same point, we know that $x_{n_r}\to L$ as $r\to\infty$.

But this is not possible since $(x_{n_r})_{r\in\mathbb N}$ is an *increasing* sequence each of whose terms are greater than $L$.

Comment: Thank you! The trick is defining a subsequence, I got you!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose to the contrary that $x_N > L$ for some $N$. Define the sequence of natural number setting $n_0=N$ and $n_i= \min\{n>n_{i-1}:x_{n}>x_{n_{i-1}}\}$. Then each $n_i$ is well-defined  since the set is non-empty (by hypothesis). So  $(x_{n_i})$ is a subsequence which does not converges to $L$. But since all the subsequence of a convergent sequence converges to the same value, we get a contradiction. $\square$

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like you're saying that every term after $x_{N}$ must be greater than its preceding term.  I don't think that's part of the premise of the theorem--instead, the premise is just that SOME term after $x_{N}$ must be greater.

Comment: @Addem: Ups I read very quickly.

Comment: @Jose Yeah, the premise says for SOME term after Xn. Can we just suppose for all n, Xn>=L, then for all K>n, Xn>L? and Why is contradict (Xn) converges to L?

Comment: We can create a subsequence which contain all those terms, an so which does not convergence to $L$ but this is a contradiction since all the subsequence of a convergence sequence converges to the same value.

Comment: @user127534: I've fixed it sorry I read very quickly :P, Hopefully this could help you.

Comment: @JoseAntonio Thank you! The trick is defining a subsequence, I got you!

Comment: @user127534: You're welcome.

Comment: @JoseAntonio I notice that actually, we should prove Xn<=L for all N, is the proof the same?

Comment: @user127534: You only need a subsequence which is does not converges to $L$. Then to the contrary suppose that $x_n> L$ for some $n$. Then by hypothesis we can find some $n_1> n$ such that $x_{n_1}>x_n$  and so forth and reached the contradiction.